# $\sigma$-algebras and sample space

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Does a $\sigma$-algebra always contain the sample space (or the full set over which it is defined) ?

I know the smallest $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega$ can be defined as $G = \{\emptyset, A, A^{c}, \Omega\}$, and the largest by the powerset of $\mathscr{P}(\Omega)$, where
$A \subset \Omega$ and $A^{c} \subset \Omega$.

The third condition for the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra states :

$A_{i} \in G$ $\rightarrow$ $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}A_{i} \in G$

But since this union will always equal $\Omega$, this seems to imply that the $\sigma$-algebra always contains the sample space.

Am I missing something here ? Are there any counter-examples ?

Comment: In definition of sigma algebra, there is one point saying that either $\Omega \in \mathcal G$ or $\emptyset \in \mathcal G$ (with second condition that $\sigma$ algebra is closed under taking complement it implies that $\Omega \in \mathcal G$ for any $\sigma-$algebra of subsets of $\Omega$

Comment: Thanks @DominikKutek!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three properties of a $\sigma$-algebra  $\mathscr{G}$ are:

i) $\emptyset \in \mathscr{G}$

ii) $A \in \mathscr{G}$ $\rightarrow$ $A^{c} \in \mathscr{G}$

iii) If $A_{i} \in \mathscr{G}$ $\rightarrow$ $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}A_{i} \in \mathscr{G}$

As pointed out in the comment by @Dominik, by property ii. we must have $\Omega \in \mathscr{G}$.

Also, since $\emptyset \cup \Omega = \Omega$, the smallest possible $\sigma$-algebra is actually $\mathscr{G}=\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ ... and not $\{\emptyset, A, A^{c}, \Omega\}$. The latter would be instead the smallest **non-degenerate** algebra.